# How to get current image's slug in WP_image_editor?

Tags: images

I’ve been writing some class and functions to modify the path of thumbnails. I extended the original `WP_Image_Editor` class to achieve custom structure.

**What i want:** to store the thumbnails in different folders based on their slugs, in the upload directory. such as : `http://example.com/uploads/medium/image.jpg`

**What i have already done:**

```
class WP_Image_Editor_Custom extends WP_Image_Editor_GD {
    public function generate_filename($prefix = NULL, $dest_path = NULL, $extension = NULL) {
        global $current_size_slug;
        // If empty, generate a prefix with the parent method get_suffix().
        if(!$prefix)
            $prefix = $this->get_suffix();

        // Determine extension and directory based on file path.
        $info = pathinfo($this->file);
        $dir  = ABSPATH."/media/";
        $ext  = $info['extension'];

        // Determine image name.
        $name = wp_basename($this->file, ".$ext");

        // Allow extension to be changed via method argument.
        $new_ext = strtolower($extension ? $extension : $ext);

        // Default to $_dest_path if method argument is not set or invalid.
        if(!is_null($dest_path) && $_dest_path = realpath($dest_path))
            $dir = $_dest_path;

        // Return our new prefixed filename.
        $slug = $current_size_slug; 
        return trailingslashit($dir)."{$slug}/{$name}.{$new_ext}";
    }
    function multi_resize($sizes) {
        $sizes = parent::multi_resize($sizes);
        foreach($sizes as $slug => $data)
            $sizes[$slug]['file'] = $slug."/".$data['file'];
            $current_size_slug = $slug;
        return $sizes;
    }
}
```

When i upload the image, the thumbnails are created properly, however the filenames are not. The `$slug` value is not passed from `multi_resize()` to generate_filename.

I tried to write the `multi_resize()` function as below:

```
class WP_Image_Editor_Custom extends WP_Image_Editor_GD {
    public function generate_filename($prefix = NULL, $dest_path = NULL, $extension = NULL) {
        global $current_size_slug;
        // If empty, generate a prefix with the parent method get_suffix().
        if(!$prefix)
            $prefix = $this->get_suffix();

        // Determine extension and directory based on file path.
        $info = pathinfo($this->file);
        $dir  = ABSPATH."/media/";
        $ext  = $info['extension'];

        // Determine image name.
        $name = wp_basename($this->file, ".$ext");

        // Allow extension to be changed via method argument.
        $new_ext = strtolower($extension ? $extension : $ext);

        // Default to $_dest_path if method argument is not set or invalid.
        if(!is_null($dest_path) && $_dest_path = realpath($dest_path))
            $dir = $_dest_path;

        // Return our new prefixed filename.
        $slug = $current_size_slug; 
        return trailingslashit($dir)."{$slug}/{$name}.{$new_ext}";
    }
    function multi_resize($sizes) {
        $sizes = parent::multi_resize($sizes);
        foreach($sizes as $slug => $data)
            $sizes[$slug]['file'] = $slug."/".$data['file'];
            $current_size_slug = $slug;
        return $sizes;
    }
}
```

Now the `$slug` is passed to `generate_filename()` but the thumbnails are all generated in uploads folder, overwriting each other. How can i do this?

I'm clueless here, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to functions.php:

```
add_filter("wp_image_editors", "my_wp_image_editors");

function my_wp_image_editors($editors) {
    array_unshift($editors, "WP_Image_Editor_Custom");
    return $editors;
}

// Include the existing classes first in order to extend them.
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . "/class-wp-image-editor.php";
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . "/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php";

class WP_Image_Editor_Custom extends WP_Image_Editor_GD {

    public function generate_filename($suffix = null, $dest_path = null, $extension = null) {
        // $suffix will be appended to the destination filename, just before the extension
        if (!$suffix) {
            $suffix = $this->get_suffix();
        }

        $dir = pathinfo($this->file, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
        $ext = pathinfo($this->file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $name = wp_basename($this->file, ".$ext");
        $new_ext = strtolower($extension ? $extension : $ext );

        if (!is_null($dest_path) && $_dest_path = realpath($dest_path)) {
            $dir = $_dest_path;
        }
        //we get the dimensions using explode, we could have used the properties of $this->file[height] but the suffix could have been provided
        $size_from_suffix = explode("x", $suffix);
        //we get the slug_name for this dimension
        $slug_name = $this->get_slug_by_size($size_from_suffix[0], $size_from_suffix[1]);

        return trailingslashit($dir) . "{$slug_name}/{$name}.{$new_ext}";
    }

    function multi_resize($sizes) {
        $sizes = parent::multi_resize($sizes);

        //we add the slug to the file path
        foreach ($sizes as $slug => $data) {
            $sizes[$slug]['file'] = $slug . "/" . $data['file'];
        }

        return $sizes;
    }

    function get_slug_by_size($width, $height) {

        // Make thumbnails and other intermediate sizes.
        $_wp_additional_image_sizes = wp_get_additional_image_sizes();

        $image_sizes = array(); //all sizes the default ones and the custom ones in one array
        foreach (get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $s) {
            $image_sizes[$s] = array('width' => '', 'height' => '', 'crop' => false);
            if (isset($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['width'])) {
                // For theme-added sizes
                $image_sizes[$s]['width'] = intval($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['width']);
            } else {
                // For default sizes set in options
                $image_sizes[$s]['width'] = get_option("{$s}_size_w");
            }

            if (isset($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['height'])) {
                // For theme-added sizes
                $image_sizes[$s]['height'] = intval($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['height']);
            } else {
                // For default sizes set in options
                $image_sizes[$s]['height'] = get_option("{$s}_size_h");
            }

            if (isset($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['crop'])) {
                // For theme-added sizes
                $image_sizes[$s]['crop'] = $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['crop'];
            } else {
                // For default sizes set in options
                $image_sizes[$s]['crop'] = get_option("{$s}_crop");
            }
        }
        $slug_name = ""; //the slug name

        if($width >= $height){
          foreach ($image_sizes as $slug => $data) { //we start checking
            if ($data['width'] == $width) {//we use only width because regardless of the height, the width is the one used for resizing in all cases with crop 1 or 0
                $slug_name = $slug;
            }
            /*
             * There could be custom added image sizes that have the same width as one of the defaults so we also use height here
             * if there are several image sizes with the same width all of them will override the previous one leaving the last one, here we get also the last one
             * since is looping the entire list, the height is used as a max value for non-hard cropped sizes
             *  */
              if ($data['width'] == $width && $data['height'] == $height) {
                  $slug_name = $slug;
              }
          }
         }else{
           foreach ($image_sizes as $slug => $data) {
              if ($data['height'] == $height) {
                  $slug_name = $slug;
              }
              if ($data['height'] == $height && $data['width'] == $width ) {
                  $slug_name = $slug;
              }
            }
         }
        return $slug_name;
    }
}
```

i know you already know almost all of this code, notice that the `generate_filename` function has been updated to the current one, you will be more interested in the `get_slug_by_size` function which is the key part that you were missing.
This is also working with custom image sizes, as can be seen here:

[image]

`home-bottom` is a image size i added. Right now wordpress has 4 different default image sizes:

```
    Array
    (
        [thumbnail] => Array // Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
            (
                [width] => 150
                [height] => 150
                [crop] => 1
            )

        [medium] => Array // Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
            (
                [width] => 300
                [height] => 300
                [crop] => 
            )

        [medium_large] => Array //Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
            (
                [width] => 768
                [height] => 0
                [crop] => 
            )

        [large] => Array // Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)
            (
                [width] => 1024
                [height] => 1024
                [crop] => 
            )

    )
// Full resolution (original size uploaded) this one is not in the array.
```

if you upload an image of `width 310` only `thumbnail` and `medium` images would be created WordPress will not create bigger ones, so with the code above, only 2 folders will be created.

Comment: I updated the code for vertical images, as for small images that are more small than the minimun image size (thumbnail by default given that you didnt add a custom one more small) there is not going to be a "resized" image only the original.

Comment: np, i think i saw 2, i feel this structure for the images better than the default since we would need to change only 1 var (the name of the folder) to change a entire set of images versus the name with dimensions...

Answer (score 1):

A code sample explaining its use case will be more helpful.
Not sure how you're going to use it, but to simply access all the slugs inside $sizes you can use this.

The multi_resize() gets its 'sizes' as a parameter, which is provided to it by wp_generate_attachment_metadata() [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L135). A simple approach to get the sizes array will be to store it in a class property. Such as

Add this before all functions.

```
public $current_size_slug = '';
```

This is generate_filename() function with necessary modifications and comments to help you understand how it works:

```
public function generate_filename( $prefix = null, $dest_path = null, $extension = null ) {
// <-- Now we have the current thumbnail slug.-->
$slug = $this->current_size_slug;
// If empty, generate a prefix with the parent method get_suffix().
if ( ! $prefix ) {
    $prefix = $this->get_suffix();
}

// Determine extension and directory based on file path.
$info = pathinfo( $this->file );
$dir  = $info['dirname'];
$ext  = $info['extension'];

// Determine image name.
$name = wp_basename( $this->file, ".$ext" );

// Allow extension to be changed via method argument.
$new_ext = strtolower( $extension ? $extension : $ext );

// Default to $_dest_path if method argument is not set or invalid.
if ( ! is_null( $dest_path ) && $_dest_path = realpath( $dest_path ) ) {
    $dir = $_dest_path;
}

// Return our new prefixed filename.
// <-- Replaced prefix with slug. -->
return trailingslashit( $dir ) . "{$slug}/{$name}.{$new_ext}"; 

}
```

This multi_resize() function which actually sets the $current_size_slug before calling _save()

```
function multi_resize( $sizes ) {
$metadata  = array();
$orig_size = $this->size;

foreach ( $sizes as $size => $size_data ) {
    if ( ! isset( $size_data['width'] ) && ! isset( $size_data['height'] ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $size_data['width'] ) ) {
        $size_data['width'] = null;
    }
    if ( ! isset( $size_data['height'] ) ) {
        $size_data['height'] = null;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $size_data['crop'] ) ) {
        $size_data['crop'] = false;
    }

    $image     = $this->_resize( $size_data['width'], $size_data['height'], $size_data['crop'] );
    $duplicate = ( ( $orig_size['width'] == $size_data['width'] ) && ( $orig_size['height'] == $size_data['height'] ) );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) && ! $duplicate ) {
        // We set the current slug before calling the save function.
        $this->current_size_slug = $size;

        $resized = $this->_save( $image );

        imagedestroy( $image );

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $resized ) && $resized ) {
            unset( $resized['path'] );
            $metadata[ $size ] = $resized;
        }
    }

    $this->size = $orig_size;
}

return $metadata;
}
```

The _save() function actually saves the file on the server, to do so it calls the generate_filename(). I hope this answers your question.

*Please consider hiring a developer for custom jobs like these if you're not comfortable with PHP and WordPress*
Do **Not** Copy and Paste code unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Replace your function multi_resize($sizes) with mine. and use $this->all_sizes where you want to use them.

Comment: I'm assuming this is what you want : http://example.com/thumbs/slug/image.jpg ? is this what you want?

Comment: You should avoid using Global variables, it's mostly harmless in this example. But it's a bad practice to use Global variables.