# Generate thumbnail for images with the same size as thumbnails

Tags: post-thumbnails

I've noticed that WordPress does not generate a thumbnail for an image if the uploaded image's size is the same as the thumbnail's size.

To make this clear, here is an example:

I have an image with a size of `300x200px`. My thumbnail's size in the WordPress setting is also `300x200`. So, when i upload this image, no thumbnail of `300x200` size will be generated, because the uploaded image **itself** is considered a thumbnail to WordPress!

I've tracked it down to `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` function, which decides not to crop an image if the image's size is equal to a thumbnail's size. [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) is the link to this function's content.

This function has a filter, as the following:

`apply_filters( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', $metadata, $attachment_id );`

How can i make this function to make the thumbnail, no matter what size?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

Following the answer by @birgire, i have included my custom `multi_resize()` function in the question:

```
function multi_resize($sizes) {
    $sizes = parent::multi_resize($sizes);

    //we add the slug to the file path
    foreach ($sizes as $slug => $data) {
        $sizes[$slug]['file'] = $slug . "/" . $data['file'];
    }

    return $sizes;
}
```

I'm using this function for some other purposes, mentioned [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/255462/94498) question.

Comment: side note: there is actually no reason that wordpress will not be able to generate a large image from a smaller one. Browsers do it, so you should be able to do it in PHP as well, might even use better heuristics than browsers can.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Yea but there's actually no point for me to reduce the quality. Still, possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to generate

```
test.jpg
test-150x150.jpg
```

instead of just:

```
test.jpg
```

when you upload an image called `test.jpg`, of size 150x150, the same as the *thumbnail* size. (*I used the 150x150 size here instead of your 300x200 to avoid confusing it with the medium size*)

This restriction is implemented in the [`multi_resize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_image_editor_gd/multi_resize/) method of the image editor classes, like `WP_Image_Editor_Imagick` and `WP_Image_Editor_GD` that extend `WP_Image_Editor`:

```
$duplicate = ( ( $orig_size['width'] == $size_data['width'] ) 
    && ( $orig_size['height'] == $size_data['height'] ) );
```

If the size is the same as the size of the original image, then it's not generated.

A possible workaround could be to extend the image class to your needs and add it to the list of available image editors through the [`wp_image_editors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_image_editors-2/) filter.

Alternatively you could try to hook into the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` to generate the missing duplicate with a help from the image editor, like the `save()` method.

Comment: That's all correct birgir, thanks. I updated the question followed by your answer, i hope you have a bit more time to help me further with this issue. Would it be enough to just set `$duplicate` to false in my custom `multi_resize()` function?

Comment: @JackJohansson, so It looks like you're already extending the image class. Just to test, you could try to override the `multi_resize()` method with the same code from the original method, but set `$duplicate` to `false`, and include your current file adjustments in the metadata as well.

Comment: Yes that's what i thought for one moment. But when i do that, i can no longer get that `$slug` data that i need to build the directory structure.

Comment: You should be able to get it inside the `$metadata` array within the original `multi_resize()` method. Looks like you're using `$sizes` confusingly, I think it would be more clear if you used `$metadata = parent::multi_resize($sizes);` etc..Then I think you can better see the relation to the original method @JackJohansson

Comment: To test, try to duplicate and override the original `multi_resize()` method where you set `$duplicate` to `false` and then right before `return $metadata;` add your `foreach ($metadata as $slug => $data) { $metadata[$slug]['file'] = $slug . "/" . $data['file'];}` Or try to add it with a filter like `wp_generate_attachment_metadata`. @JackJohansson

Comment: Thank you birgir. I already accepted the answer. Just one final question, the `wp_get_attachment_image()` is still returning the original image rather than thumbnail as `srcset`, however, `src` works fine. Do you have any idea where do i hook to fix this?

Comment: I've not looked into that, but I wonder if you could check out  the `wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta` or `wp_calculate_image_srcset` filter? @JackJohansson

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem i create a custom behavior in functions.php restricted to thumbnails not been created yet and just the same size of the image. As @JackJohansson explain, the function work in wp_generate_attachment_metadata filter.

```
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'same_size_image');

function same_size_image($meta){
  global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

  $file = wp_upload_dir();
  $file = trailingslashit($file['basedir']).$meta['file'];
  $info = getimagesize($file);
  $image = wp_get_image_editor($file);

  foreach ($_wp_additional_image_sizes as $label => $op) {
    if (!isset($meta['sizes'][$label])) {
        $width = $op['width'];
        $height = $op['height'];
        $new_file_path = preg_replace('/\.(.+$)/', '-'.$width.'x'.$height.".$1", $file);
        if ($info[0] == $width) $image->save($new_file_path);
    }
  }

  return $meta;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Wordpress should automatically create all specified sizes of an image when it's uploaded to the media library. By specified I mean the sizes that are supplied by the parent and/or child themes with:

```
add_image_size('name', 320, 200);
```

.. along with any WP defaults. The above is just a simple example of creating an image derivative for WP. If you want it to create a thumbnail of a specified size every time, you can call this in functions.php (or an include file your theme is calling).

Are you looking for a specific size or just the 100x100 default?

Comment: Thank you but my problem isn't this, the problem is when the uploaded image is 100x100px , the thumbnail isn't generated (since the uploaded image is considered a thumbnail itself).

Comment: wordpress API do not auto generate images that are bigger than the uploaded image, you can not use it, and need to work around the limitation

Comment: @MarkKaplun My apologies mark, but i don't see how that's relevant to the question. I never asked to create an image larger than original.

Comment: @JackJohansson, wrong choice of words, wordpress generates only smaller images. The actual answer will most likely be applicable to both cases (equal and bigger)

Answer (score -3):

Hello i am not sure this is what you are looking for but i think this would help

`add_image_size( 'thumbnail', '100px', '100px', true );`

use either `true` or `FALSE` statement to declear wheather or not to resize image, the above code would produce an image of almost exactly 100px x 100px . for all images how ever small walk arounds needed to be don eon the css.

Comment: Thank you but my problem isn't this, the problem is when the uploaded image is 100x100px , the thumbnail isn't generated (since the uploaded image is considered a thumbnail itself).

Comment: wow, never saw that coming, why the down vote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote by the way. Someone downvoted all answers.