# Why should I use "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders" option? (Cons/Pros)

Tags: images, directory, seo

What is the benefit of using (advantage/disadvantage)

```
Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders
```

option? Why would I want to organize my folder structure like this ? Is there SEO advantages ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the many optional features in WordPress.There is no real benefit in using any of these 2 structures, but here is some details for you:

**Organization:**

When you are building a website which will have a lot of uploads, it is always a good option to go for the year / month structure. You might end up with 100,000 uploads in a single folder if you don't.

As you can imagine, sorting, reading and listing these files will get a long time. There was a time when old file systems used to support limited files in a single folder ( They still do now, but it's way more than before), so you had to make more folders to be able to save the images.

A website with 50K images and 5 thumbnail sizes will end up having 300k images in a single folder!

**SEO benefits**

There is no actual benefit of having a year / month structure on your files when it comes to SEO. Search engines have other tools to understand your contents, such as [Structured data](http://schema.org/) or HTML5 structure, which let's the search engine understand different parts of a page without using a MicroData structure.

**Custom templates - Security**

Some users (such as me) prefer to have their website deeply customized, including default folder names. I myself have changed the name all `wp-content`, `wp-admin`, `uploads` and `wp-includes` folder. Some directly, some through rewriting.

So the first moment a visitor visits the website, it's not easy to understand whether this website is powered by WordPress or not. It also makes it a bit more difficult for a newbie hacker to determine the CMS of the website.

However, with the year / month structure turned to ON, it needs one second to realize that this website is using WordPress to power up.

Although there are several ways to go around this, but still, some do prefer it.

There can be many other things added to this list, their all optional, such as the above list.

I hope this helps you decide what to choose about this.

Comment: offtopic, but if you think you directory structure prevents anyone from knowing you run a wordpress, than you are very wrong. Actually with 27% of the internet powered by wordpress, no hacker will even bother to check if your site is wordpress or not.

Comment: Please read the answer again?

Comment: I am referring to the security part. There is no real security in that

Comment: Yes i'm not securing my WP against Langley, just against some kids who use my `xmlrpc.php` to spam, the moment they notice it's a WP site.

Comment: especially kids use a ready made kits, they do not waste their time inspecting your site, they just run the kit

Comment: Ok sir my answer is naive, please forgive me you almighty GOD of disagreement. This answer and also [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/256590/94498) question.

Comment: sorry if you have the illusion that I write things for your benefit, it is for the benefit of other people that might google up this question, and might get some ideas from your answer

Comment: I see. You were already so nice in your answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

OMG, is there nothing else in the world except for SEO this days?

Each OS has limitations and/or performance degradation on the number of files that are in a directory. used to be a limit of 32k files on linux, but this might have changed so don't trust me on exact numbers here, but think how long will it take you to just show a list of 30k files in your favorite FTP software, and how hard it will be to find anything there.

PROs? so small it is not worth mentioning, but if you insist, you might save some bytes in the OS's directory/files related cache. And obviously some bytes saved in disk storage.