# Rename media files generated during upload

Tags: images, uploads, media

I am trying to modify the default media names in WordPress to remove the dimensions from the files and replace them with a simple suffix.

For example:

- imageA-300x300.jpg
- imageA-480x480.jpg
- imageA-1024x1024.jpg

Would become

- imageA-thumb.jpg
- imageA-medium.jpg
- imageA-large.jpg

How can I do this? So far, I've tried by adding a filter in wp_handle_upload_prefilter but it seems to only modify the original name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using my own code from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255462/how-to-get-current-images-slug-in-wp-image-editor/256498#256498), i updated the logic to add the name of the image size instead of the suffix, try adding this to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter("wp_image_editors", "my_wp_image_editors");

function my_wp_image_editors($editors) {
    array_unshift($editors, "WP_Image_Editor_Custom");
    return $editors;
}

// Include the existing classes first in order to extend them.
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . "/class-wp-image-editor.php";
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . "/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php";

class WP_Image_Editor_Custom extends WP_Image_Editor_GD {

    public function generate_filename($suffix = null, $dest_path = null, $extension = null) {
        // $suffix will be appended to the destination filename, just before the extension
        if (!$suffix) {
            $suffix = $this->get_suffix();
        }

        $dir = pathinfo($this->file, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
        $ext = pathinfo($this->file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $name = wp_basename($this->file, ".$ext");
        $new_ext = strtolower($extension ? $extension : $ext );

        if (!is_null($dest_path) && $_dest_path = realpath($dest_path)) {
            $dir = $_dest_path;
        }
        //we get the dimensions using explode, we could have used the properties of $this->file[height] but the suffix could have been provided
        $size_from_suffix = explode("x", $suffix);
        //we get the slug_name for this dimension
        $slug_name = $this->get_slug_by_size($size_from_suffix[0], $size_from_suffix[1]);

        return trailingslashit($dir) . "{$name}-{$slug_name}.{$new_ext}";
    }

    function get_slug_by_size($width, $height) {

        // Make thumbnails and other intermediate sizes.
        $_wp_additional_image_sizes = wp_get_additional_image_sizes();

        $image_sizes = array(); //all sizes the default ones and the custom ones in one array
        foreach (get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $s) {
            $image_sizes[$s] = array('width' => '', 'height' => '', 'crop' => false);
            if (isset($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['width'])) {
                // For theme-added sizes
                $image_sizes[$s]['width'] = intval($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['width']);
            } else {
                // For default sizes set in options
                $image_sizes[$s]['width'] = get_option("{$s}_size_w");
            }

            if (isset($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['height'])) {
                // For theme-added sizes
                $image_sizes[$s]['height'] = intval($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['height']);
            } else {
                // For default sizes set in options
                $image_sizes[$s]['height'] = get_option("{$s}_size_h");
            }

            if (isset($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['crop'])) {
                // For theme-added sizes
                $image_sizes[$s]['crop'] = $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['crop'];
            } else {
                // For default sizes set in options
                $image_sizes[$s]['crop'] = get_option("{$s}_crop");
            }
        }
        $slug_name = ""; //the slug name

        if($width >= $height){
          foreach ($image_sizes as $slug => $data) { //we start checking
            if ($data['width'] == $width) {//we use only width because regardless of the height, the width is the one used for resizing in all cases with crop 1 or 0
                $slug_name = $slug;
            }
            /*
             * There could be custom added image sizes that have the same width as one of the defaults so we also use height here
             * if there are several image sizes with the same width all of them will override the previous one leaving the last one, here we get also the last one
             * since is looping the entire list, the height is used as a max value for non-hard cropped sizes
             *  */
              if ($data['width'] == $width && $data['height'] == $height) {
                  $slug_name = $slug;
              }
          }
         }else{
           foreach ($image_sizes as $slug => $data) {
              if ($data['height'] == $height) {
                  $slug_name = $slug;
              }
              if ($data['height'] == $height && $data['width'] == $width ) {
                  $slug_name = $slug;
              }
            }
         }
        return $slug_name;
    }
}
```

i also removed the unnecessary code, this will also work with custom image sizes, as can be seen here:

[image]

`home-bottom` is a custom image size i have.

Comment: Oh wow, it works flawlessly! Now gotta understand all this, thanks A LOT! :D